# How to use RichFaces4.0 with JSF2.0? How to configure View Handler for RichFaces4.0?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf-2, richfaces, facelets

I am using a simple example program using RichFaces 4.0 but unfortunately I am not able to configure the view handler for Richfaces 4.0.

I have following libraries in my WEB-INF folder

commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
guava-r08.jar
jsf-api-2.0.4-b09.jar
jsf-impl-2.0.4-b09.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.20110209-M6.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.20110209-M6.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.20110209-M6.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.20110209-M6.jar
sac-1.3.jar

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>

    <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>

    <param-value>true</param-value>

</context-param>

<context-param>

    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>

    <param-value>true</param-value>

</context-param>

<context-param>

    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses</param-name>

    <param-value>false</param-value>

</context-param>

<context-param>

    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>

    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>

</context-param>

<context-param>

    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>

    <param-value>server</param-value>

</context-param>

<context-param>

    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>

    <param-value>Development</param-value>

</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>

 <login-config>

    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>

 </login-config>
```

my faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

index.jsp

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
```

start.xhtml

```
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"

  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"

  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"

  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

RichFaces

```
  <rich:panel header="RichFaces">
```

What is happening is that as I do not have any view handler so when I run the application I am being prompted to download the file from the browser?

If I include jsf-facelets.jar and configure it in the faces-config.xml then i get tag lib error while deploying. The browser does not  display any RichFaces4.0 component only text is displayed.

See below error for reference.

INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/RichFacesJSF20] has already been started

22-Feb-2011 19:08:52 com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig loadImplicit

INFO: Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-core.taglib.xml

22-Feb-2011 19:08:52 com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig loadImplicit

INFO: Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml

22-Feb-2011 19:08:52 com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig loadImplicit

INFO: Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-ui.taglib.xml

22-Feb-2011 19:08:52 com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig loadImplicit

INFO: Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jstl-core.taglib.xml

22-Feb-2011 19:08:52 com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig loadImplicit

INFO: Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jstl-fn.taglib.xml

22-Feb-2011 19:08:52 com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig loadImplicit

INFO: Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.0.4-b09.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml

22-Feb-2011 19:08:52 com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig loadImplicit

SEVERE: Error Loading Library: jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.20110209-M6.jar!/META-INF/a4j.taglib.xml

java.io.IOException: Error parsing [jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.20110209-M6.jar!/META-INF/a4j.taglib.xml]:

```
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:410)

    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431)

    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)

    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)

    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218)

    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149)

    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100)

    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)

    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)

    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)

    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)

    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)

    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:59)

    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)

    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)

    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/modhas2/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/RichFacesJSF20/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.20110209-M6.jar!/META-INF/a4j.taglib.xml@2,255]

```
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.error(TagLibraryConfig.java:376)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1318)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)

    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)

    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)

    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:407)

    ... 39 more
```

Please suggest on how to use RichFaces4.0 using Facelets JSF2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure the view handler when using RichFaces 4. Facelets is the default view handler that's used. I'd recommend to create a new RichFaces 4 project using RichFaces Maven archetype - you will get everything you need created at once.